# Black screen when programmatically creating navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am programmatically creating a navigation controller like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.mainMenuViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.mainMenuViewController;
    UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.window.rootViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [[GKHelper sharedInstance] authenticateLocalPlayer];
    return YES;
}
```

And, while Xcode seems perfectly happy with this, I am getting a black screen when I launch my app with this code. When I comment it out, and just user the arrow in the storyboard it works fine but I don't get a navigation controller. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First: You could add a navigation controller using story board. But that would be a different question, right?

Comment: Yeah. That's what I was doing before. But it was impossible to completely hide it as I am doing an all-custom UI. So I am trying to get it programmatically so I can have all custom UI elements without the cliche navigation elements.

Comment: Second: you Do have a root view controller and a navigation controller. But where do you actually add, layout, colorize etc. your views? Do you do this in loadView or viewDidLoad within MainMenuViewController? If you have a XIB file for the views then you did not load it, as far as we can see in the code sniplet. If you want to load a single view out of a storyboard, which is possible, then you don't do it. So what do you want to do in order to actually display your views?

Comment: As you can see, I want the MainMenuViewController to be by root view controller. I alloc and init it, then assign it to be the window's root view controller. Somehow this doesn't seem to be working though.

Comment: All right. But when you do not want to see the cliche ui elements, why the heck to you use a navigation controller at all? If you want your own custom navigation then you could do this simply based on modal presentations. The navigation controller is only there to help you with the overhead. But when you want to do that in a different manner, then using UINavigationController may not be the best choice.

Comment: As PACan says in his answer - the code does exactly what you coded. You did everything right as far as I can see. But you did not add any acutal view. As there is nothing to be shown, the screen remains empty. You are on the right track dude. I am a big supporter of doing everything programmatically whil learning the bolts and nuts. Your next step would be overwriting the appropriate method within your view controller and actually crate and add some UIView sublass objects

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to create the `UIWindow` object before you try to send it messages.  You also need to set your navigation controller as the window's `rootViewController`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.mainMenuViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.mainMenuViewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [[GKHelper sharedInstance] authenticateLocalPlayer];
    return YES;
}
```

#### UPDATE

I see that you are trying to transition from using a storyboard.  Your `MainMenuViewController` needs to create or load its view somehow.  When you were using a storyboard, your `MainMenuViewController` was loading its view from the storyboard.  You have three options:

1. You can load the `MainMenuViewController` from the storyboard, so that it loads its view from the storyboard.  In the storyboard, give your `MainMenuViewController` an identifier.  Let's say you set the identifier to `MainMenu`.  Then you can load the `MainMenuViewController` from the storyboard like this:

   ```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
   self.mainMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainMenu"];
   ```
2. You can create a `.xib` file containing the view for `MainMenuViewController`.  If you name it `MainMenuViewController.xib`, the `MainMenuViewController` will use it automatically (when you're not loading the view controller from the storyboard).
3. You can implement `-[MainMenuViewController loadView]` to create the view and store it in `self.view`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing anything, because there is nothing to show really :). When you do this programmatically, you have to :
1. Instantiate the navigation controller
2. Instantiate the view controllers you want to put in it.
3. Create an array of these objects
4. Add the array to navigation controller
5. Set navController to view.

Code snippet:

```
    UINavigationController *navContr = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
    FirstViewController *firstViewContr = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    MapViewController *mapContr = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
    NSArray *vcArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: mapContr, firstViewContr, nil];
    [navContr setViewControllers:vcArray];
    [self.window setRootViewController:navContr];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

Comment: You do not need to create things this way. The code posted by the OP, for creating the initial nav controller, is correct.